Raspberry PI4 on Ubuntu Desktop 23.10: Why is wifi 5GHz capped to 100mbit and wifi 2.4GHz capped to 54mbit?
I'm new to Raspberry pi's. Last week I installed Ubuntu Desktop 23.10 on my Raspberry PI4.
My Raspberry is in a closet where my router also is.
With Iperf3 I get 100mbit download speed on wifi 5GHz and 24mbit on 2.4 GHz. Signal is very strong, max.
It looks to a software problem to me. When I go to advanced network configuration (the purple icon), where you can choose band, I see for 5GHz only 802.11 A is selectable and for 2.4GHz only B/G is selectable.
When I do "sudo iwconfig" I see for the 5GHz connection: "433mbits/s" speed
and for the 2.4GHz connection I see: "24 mbits/s" speed.
This is strange, because my TPLink VR600v3 wifi 5 router offers atleast 866 mbit/s on the 5GHz connections and atleast 144 mbits/s on the 2.4 GHz connection.
Does anyone have this problem? It looks like a software (on the Raspberry pi side) problem to me.
I browsed a lot of forum posts on Rasberry PI4 bad wifi reception, but all blame it on weak wifi signal, but thats not the case. The Raspberry is 20cm away from the wifi router, and the signal is max.
Plus that iwconfig says it is connected at 433mbit/s on the 5GHz band, but Iperf3 gets at max 100mbits thru.
So it looks to me the hardware is getting max wifi signal strenght and the connection is actually 433mbit/s, but due to some software/driver error only 100mbits/s gets through.
I already updated firmware to LATEST: Thu May 11 06:26:03 UTC 2023 (1683786363) and VL805_FW: LATEST: 000138c0
Anyone an idea what to do?
Thank you!

It is unclear what you are asking as you have provided little diagnostics. The (allegedly) higher rates (866Mbits/s) require a MIMO multi antenna system at both ends. The Pi only has a single antenna. If the Pi is next to the router why not use Ethernet?

do you get the same lack of performance using Raspberry Pi OS?

I Made a screenshot from iperf3 tests between the raspberry pi (raspbhian pi os x64)
[https://ibb.co/6WVQqWn]
The 433mbits/s that the PI4 on the 5GHz can deliver is fine with me.
The problem however is that the Raspberry PI4 cannot put more data thru that 433mbit/s connection than 100mbit/s.
Which again, to me seems much like a driver/software problem on the Raspberry.
When I do Iperf3 on the 1Gb/s ethernet port, I reach around 950mbit/s so thats fine.

Ps. I tested on Ubuntu Deskstop 23.10 64bit and just 10min ago also on Rasphian PI OS 64bit. Same results.

Sorry, I had problems posting the picture. The url is https://ibb.co/6WVQqWn

So, does anyone have an idea why the raspberrypi4 can only throughput 100mbit/s on 5ghz wifi while its connected at 433mbit/s?
